# Excel VBA 2013 - Getting the start time and end time of the value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the Start Time and End Time of the same values and delete the entire row of it.

```
Name       Start time    End time
Michael    2:57:00 PM   3:04:10 PM
Michael    3:04:10 PM   3:12:29 PM
Michael    3:12:29 PM   3:14:57 PM
Sarah      3:19:53 PM   3:20:00 PM
Sarah      3:20:00 PM   3:20:23 PM
Michael    3:20:23 PM   3:23:49 PM
```

Output will be

```
Michael    2:57:00 PM   3:14:57 PM
Sarah      3:19:53 PM   3:20:23 PM
Michael    3:20:23 PM   3:23:49 PM
```

Sorry. I really don't know Macro. If someone can help me please. 
It would much appreciated!

Thanks!

UPDATE:

What I have is only deleting the duplicates. Which I think is not possible.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? this is no "free code for you" site (I suggest thats the reason for the downvote)

Comment: You could use formula for this also, array formula, like MIN(if(a1:a10="Michael",b1:b10))

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the conditional [MAX](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) and [MIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7) time values for each name in column A. These values need to be in the first occurrence of the name.

```
Sub min_max_del()
    Dim rw As Long, cr As Long, lr As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For rw = lr To 2 Step -1
                If rw = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, "A"), .Columns(1), 0) Then
                    .Cells(rw, 2) = Evaluate("min(if('" & .Parent.Name & "'!A2:A" & lr & "=A" & rw & ", '" & .Parent.Name & "'!B2:B" & lr & "))")
                    .Cells(rw, 3) = Evaluate("max(if('" & .Parent.Name & "'!A2:A" & lr & "=A" & rw & ", '" & .Parent.Name & "'!C2:C" & lr & "))")
                End If
            Next rw
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Once the times have been properly collated, the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) will get rid of extraneous entries.

[image: min_max_times_before]        [image: min_max_times_after]
                   <sup>sample data before</sup>                                                   <sup>sample data after</sup>